# Issue with fetching WeatherKit data on widget

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, widgetkit, weatherkit

I am trying to get the user's current weather condition using `WeatherKit` on the widget, the main app is working fine. But the widget app is not working at all, I mean it doesn't fetch any data from weather service. I have enabled weatherkit on both main and widget app ID, and also added WeatherKit capabllity for both targets.

When I try to fetch data nothing is happening, even the widget's debugger doesn't give me any logs!

Here is my code:

```
 func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        Task {
            await viewModel.getCurrentWeather() //fetching data
            
            var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
            // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
            let currentDate = Date()
            for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
                print(viewModel.locationManager.locationName)
                let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .minute, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: entryDate, weather: viewModel.currentWeather)
                entries.append(entry)
            }
            let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
            print(completion)
        }
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    let date: Date
    let weather: Weather
}

struct Forecast_WidgetsEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) var type
    var body: some View {
        DailyForecast1(weather: entry.weather)
    }
}
```

I also enabled `Widget Wants Location` in the widget info.plist to get user current location.

Here is WeatherViewModel class codes:

```
@MainActor class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let locationManager = LocationManager()
    @Published var currentWeather: Weather = .empty()
    @Published var isLoading = true
    
    init() { }
    
    func getCurrentWeather() async {
        print("fetching data...")
        isLoading = true
        do {
            guard let currentLocation = locationManager.lastLocation else { return }
            let weather = try await WeatherService.shared.weather(for: currentLocation)
            self.currentWeather = Weather(temperature: weather.currentWeather.temperature.value,
                                          condition: weather.currentWeather.condition.description.capitalized,
                                          symbolName: weather.currentWeather.symbolName,
                                          hightTemp: weather.dailyForecast.first?.highTemperature.value ?? 0.0,
                                          lowTemp: weather.dailyForecast.first?.lowTemperature.value ?? 0.0,
                                          dailyWeathers: weather.dailyForecast.forecast,
                                          hourlyWeathers: weather.hourlyForecast.forecast,
                                          daylight: weather.currentWeather.isDaylight)
            isLoading = false
        } catch {
            isLoading = false
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: @loremipsum I don’t get any log from debugger!!! Even a simple print()

Comment: Put it in a Text, throw the error catch it and put the description on the screen. Something you should be doing anyway the user should know if there is an issue.

Comment: Did you find an answer to your problem? 
I'm also having the same problem. CoreLocation (user location, geocoding, etc) is working fine. But anytime I try to use the async await version of the WetherKit to get the current weather, the widget goes blank. But that's only in the device! In the simulator is working fine...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dow do I use WeatherKit Swift framework to fetch the weather inside a Widget Extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236895/dow-do-i-use-weatherkit-swift-framework-to-fetch-the-weather-inside-a-widget-ext)