# First add of my complication on apple watch is blank

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchos, widgetkit, apple-watch-complication

I am developing an app with apple watch complications. When I first add one of the complication to the watch face it stays blank. When I tap on the complication the app opens and the complication on the watch face is displayed after closing the app again. Same behavior when I add a second complication on the same watch face or even another. Both the new and the old one is showing up.
Is there a problem with my timeline provider or are the API calls taking too long?

```
import WidgetKit
import CoreLocation

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    let locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .placeholder, recentMeasurements: [])
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        if context.isPreview {
            let station = Station.placeholder
            let recentMeasurements = Station.measurmentsPlaceholder
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: station, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)
            completion(entry)
        } else {
            Task {
                let station = await APIService.getStations().first!
                let recentMeasurements = await APIService.getStationMeasurements(station: station, days: 7)
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: station, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)
                completion(entry)
            }
        }
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        Task {
            let stations = await APIService.getStations()
            let station = locationManager.getNearestStation(in: stations) ?? stations.first!
            let recentMeasurements = await APIService.getStationMeasurements(station: station, days: 7)
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: station, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)
            let secondEntry = SimpleEntry(date: .now.advanced(by: 60 * 30), station: station, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)

            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry, secondEntry], policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit (18.02.2023):** Provider with Result

```
import WidgetKit
import CoreLocation

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    let locationManager = LocationManager()
    
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .success(Station.placeholder), recentMeasurements: .success([]))
    }
    
    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        if context.isPreview {
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .success(Station.placeholder), recentMeasurements: .success(Station.measurmentsPlaceholder))
            completion(entry)
        } else {
            Task {
                guard let stations = try? await APIService.getStations(),
                      let station = stations.first
                else {
                    completion(SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .failure(ProviderError.stationFetch), recentMeasurements: .failure(ProviderError.stationFetch)))
                    return
                }
                guard let recentMeasurements = try? await APIService.getStationMeasurements(station: station, days: 7)
                else {
                    completion(SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .failure(ProviderError.measurementsFetch), recentMeasurements: .failure(ProviderError.measurementsFetch)))
                    return
                }
                let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: .success(station), recentMeasurements: .success(recentMeasurements))
                completion(entry)
            }
        }
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<SimpleEntry>) -> ()) {
        Task {
            let stationResult: Result<Station, Error>
            let station: Station?
            if let stations = try? await APIService.getStations() {
                station = locationManager.getNearestStation(in: stations) ?? stations.first!
                stationResult = .success(station!)
            }
            else {
                station = nil
                stationResult = .failure(ProviderError.stationFetch)
            }
            let recentMeasurements: Result<[Measurement], Error>
            if let result = try? await APIService.getStationMeasurements(station: station!, days: 7) {
                recentMeasurements = .success(result)
            }
            else {
                recentMeasurements = .failure(ProviderError.measurementsFetch)
            }
            let entry = SimpleEntry(date: .now, station: stationResult, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)
            let secondEntry = SimpleEntry(date: .now.advanced(by: 60 * 30), station: stationResult, recentMeasurements: recentMeasurements)

            let timeline = Timeline(entries: [entry, secondEntry], policy: .atEnd)
            completion(timeline)
        }
    }
}

enum ProviderError: Error {
    case stationFetch
    case measurementsFetch
}
```

Data fetching function:

```
static func getJSON<T: Decodable>(from path: String) async throws -> [T] {
    guard let url = URL(string: path) else { return [] }
        
    let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
    let collection = try JSONDecoder().decode([T].self, from: data)
    return collection
}
```

Comment: You should be handling errors instead of just ignoring https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236895/how-do-i-use-weatherkit-swift-framework-to-fetch-the-weather-inside-a-widget-ext/75237499#75237499

Comment: `case .failure(let error): Text(error.localizedDescription)`
I implemented as you said, but it still shows nothing. Not even an error message.

Comment: You’ll have to walk through the code step by step and check it.

Comment: Edited the question. Is this the implementation you recommend?

Comment: It seems better but there is no way to diagnose from my end here, I would have to sit with the project and run line by line. Check line by line, if this isn't catching errors by guess would be that somewhere in the code you aren't showing there is an inconsistency or timing issue. But that would be a massive amount of code.

Comment: You could be crashing somewhere, which leads to hard to find issues.  Also, how is your API doing the download?  You need to be using `downloadTask` on `URLSession`.  The other "normal" downloads won't work because your widget may be paused and/or restarted multiple times during the download.

Comment: I added the fetching method. is this false then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with filtering the data in the view.
Thanks for the help.