# Convert the async Throwing Expression to a Result

Tags: swift, swift-concurrency

According to [Preserving the Results of a Throwing Expression](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/preserving-the-results-of-a-throwing-expression) documentation it is possible to convert throwing expression into `Result` type as follows:

```
let singleSample = Result { try UnreliableRandomGenerator().random() }
```

Is it also possible to convert `async` throwing expression into `Result` type like:

```
let singleSample = Result { try await UnreliableRandomGenerator().random() }
```

Comment: Find an example to test with and see what happens.

Comment: @matt How are they opposites? Aren't they instead orthogonal/independent?

Comment: You could do it with a do try catch, I use it when I have some inner function that can “throw” but I don’t consider an inner throw worthy of terminating the whole operation such as decoding an array, partial values are better than no values and the error doesn’t get ignored.

Comment: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75236895/how-do-i-use-weatherkit-swift-framework-to-fetch-the-weather-inside-a-widget-ext/75237499#75237499) is a sample, widgets is another good place since there is no built in way to present errors.

Comment: @matt "The point of the async/await revolution is that you don't need Result any more." `Result` doesn't really have anything to do with sync/async code, it can be used for both. I actually think `Result` still has value, since it has strongly typed errors, which unfortunately the language doesn't support with `throws`. If only the call-sites wouldn't become cumbersome when using `Result` instead of throwing methods...

Comment: For now, I just got `let singleSample2 = await Result.make { try await UnreliableRandomGenerator().asyncRandom() }`, where I have made `extension Result where Failure == Error { static func make(catching body: () async throws -> Success) async -> Result { do { let output = try await body(); return .success(output) } catch { return .failure(error) } } }`, I guess there are room for improvement if the behavior doesn't exist already. But I guess the issue is the `init` with an await inside.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no built-in way. You cannot pass an async closure to the `init` in stdlib today. It is pretty trivial to add (based on the [stdlib code](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/dabfcb284ccd4bb47c377834401efc1b5c213505/stdlib/public/core/Result.swift#L175-L188)):

```
extension Result where Failure == Swift.Error {
  public init(catching body: () async throws -> Success) async {
    do {
      self = .success(try await body())
    } catch {
      self = .failure(error)
    }
  }
}
```

But note that this makes the `init` async, so your code would need to be:

```
let singleSample = await Result { try await UnreliableRandomGenerator().random() }
                   ^^^^^
```

This would of course have to be called in an async context.

It's possible that what you're trying to do is make a "Future" so you can pass it through synchronous contexts. That already exists. It's called `Task`:

```
let singleSample = Task { try await UnreliableRandomGenerator().random() }
```

When you want to resolve this into a Result, you can await its `.result` property:

```
let result = await singleSample.result
```

Or you can skip the Result, and access its value directly with `try-value`:

```
let result = try await singleSample.value
```

In many cases, Result isn't all that useful in the Structured Concurrency world. It's better to use `try` and `await` directly. But it can still be very helpful for storing in properties, passing through channels that allow errors, and interacting with non-structured code, so the `.result` property on Task is very welcome, and it's nice that it easily can convert to and from `throws`.